# Sort Table fields by date Oldest to newest

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have this code and I'm so stuck. I need to sort it by the oldest date first but i cant find any solutions any toughs ?

```php
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

    <div class="nav1">
            <p>Upcoming Expiration Dates</p>
    </div>

<div class="data"   style=" width:80%; margin:-31px auto auto 89px;  ">

            <ul>
                    <li style="font-size: 20px; background-color:#9E9494;">Name</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                    <li style="font-size: 20px; background-color:#9E9494;">Expire Date</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                    <li style="font-size: 20px; background-color:#9E9494;">License Type</li>
            </ul>
<?php
/* Start Registered_Nurses */
$select="SELECT * FROM registered_nurses INNER JOIN licenses ON registered_nurses.id= licenses.id where professional_license BETWEEN '$cdate' AND DATE_ADD('$cdate', INTERVAL 135675 DAY) and '$cdate' ";
$m=mysql_query($select);
while($f=mysql_fetch_array($m))
{
    if($f[6]>=$cdate)
    {
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; '>";
        echo "<a href='upcom_nurse_edit.php?id=$f[0]&lt=professional license' style='color:#6C89D1;'>$f[1]</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:#6C89D1; '>";
        echo $f[6];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:#6C89D1;'>";
        echo "professional license";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }   
}
$select="SELECT * FROM registered_nurses INNER JOIN licenses ON registered_nurses.id= licenses.id where professional_license BETWEEN '$cdate' - INTERVAL 135675 DAY AND '$cdate' ";
$m=mysql_query($select);

while($f=mysql_fetch_array($m))
{
    if($f[6]<$cdate)
    {
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1;'>";
        echo "<a href='upcom_nurse_edit.php?id=$f[0]&lt=professional license' style='color:red;'>$f[1]</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:red; '>";
        echo $f[6];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:red;'>";
        echo "professional license";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }

}

$select1="SELECT * FROM registered_nurses INNER JOIN licenses ON registered_nurses.id= licenses.id where license_verification BETWEEN '$cdate' AND DATE_ADD('$cdate', INTERVAL 135675 DAY) and '$cdate' ";
$m1=mysql_query($select1);
while($f1=mysql_fetch_array($m1))
{
    if($f1[7]>=$cdate)
    {

        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc;'>";
        echo "<a href='upcom_nurse_edit.php?id=$f1[0]&lt=License Verification' style='color:#6C89D1;'>$f1[1]</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc; color:#6C89D1;'>";
        echo $f1[7];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc; color:#6C89D1;'>";
        echo "License Verification";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
$select1="SELECT * FROM registered_nurses INNER JOIN licenses ON registered_nurses.id= licenses.id where license_verification BETWEEN '$cdate' - INTERVAL 135675 DAY AND '$cdate' ";
$m1=mysql_query($select1);
while($f1=mysql_fetch_array($m1))
{
    if($f1[7]<$cdate)
    {

        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc;'>";
        echo "<a href='upcom_nurse_edit.php?id=$f1[0]&lt=License Verification' style='color:red;'>$f1[1]</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc; color:red;'>";
        echo $f1[7];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#cccccc; color:red;'>";
        echo "License Verification";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}

$select2="SELECT * FROM registered_nurses INNER JOIN licenses ON registered_nurses.id= licenses.id where cpr BETWEEN '$cdate' AND DATE_ADD('$cdate', INTERVAL 135675 DAY) and '$cdate' ";
$m2=mysql_query($select2);
while($f2=mysql_fetch_array($m2))
{
    if($f2[8]>=$cdate)
    {
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1;'>";
        echo "<a href='upcom_nurse_edit.php?id=$f2[0]&lt=CPR' style='color:#6C89D1;' >$f2[1]</a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:#6C89D1;'>";
        echo $f2[8];
        echo "</li>";
        echo "<li style='background-color:#f1f1f1; color:#6C89D1;'>";
        echo "CPR";
        echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a whole bloatload of code...

If your question is how to return a set of rows from a database query in a particular sequence...

specify that sequence you want in an **`ORDER BY`** clause in the SQL text.

Assuming that `professional_license` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column, and you want the rows from the query returned with the oldest values in that column first, your query would look something like this:

```
 SELECT ...
   FROM ...
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY professional_license ASC
```

Replace `ASC` with `DESC` if you want the rows in reverse order. It's possible to specify multiple expressions in the ORDER BY clause... if two rows have the same value for `professional_license`, then  the next expression would be used to determine what order the rows with matching values of `professional_license` would be returned in. For example:

```
  ORDER BY professional_license ASC, name ASC
```

Follow that same pattern for your other queries, specifying the expressions you want the resultset "ordered by" in the `ORDER BY` clause.

(If you were asking a different question, it wasn't clear.)

Answer (score 0):

HI In your query just use orderby clause as `ORDER BY date asc`